# Apache2 process never ending - how do I determine why?

Tags: php, mysql, apache2

So I just set up a new VPS, and as soon as I turn it on (MaxClients set to 140) maxclients will be reached, and apache processes don't stop ending until they reach timeout (15 seconds).

How can I further debug this to determine why they're not ending?

Unfortunately it's a production box, which is why maxclients is reached so quickly after an apache restart.

I'm running Apache 2.2.16 on ubuntu 10.10, kernel 2.6.18, and PHP 5.3.3

MySQL is running on a separate server (Note: I have a hunch that maybe the processes aren't ending due to something MySQL related, but I'm not sure what to look for)  In the past I had MySQL/PHP on the same server and everything was fine, since I've moved to 2 separate I've been running into this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curl was being called on multiple pages and there was no timeout set, so it went to max execution time.

I've since fixed!  strace -p is a life saver!

Answer (score 1):

This depends very much on your configuration. If you have keep-alive active, then it is absolutly legal for the processes to wait.

Tell us more about your configuration and check (using netstat -np) which connections are still active.

Comment: It definitely has to be MySQL, I'm not sure why Apache waits to end... I'm guessing maybe some of the PHP code never closes the MySQL connection, and then it just hangs waiting until KeepAlive is complete, then Apache is killed.  What is strange is on my other host there were never any problems (same configuration). As soon as I moved to a dedicated MySQL server this problem came up.

Comment: As soon as I hit 140 MySQL connections, everything basically stops and Apache keeps spinning.  Anyone have any ideas on how to debug this?